# How to get data by datetime logic in sql

Tags: sql-server, datetime-format

I have date(dt col name) column in est.
If i execute query between '7:30pm'EST and '11:59' Est timezone.i should get previous day information and if i execute after 12:00  i need to get today's information.

I have tried this:

```sql
Case when getdate() between '2021-03-09 7:30:00' and '2021-03-09 11:59:00'
Then dt=getdate() -1 
else dt=getdate()
```

Comment: `GETDATE()` returns a `datetime` not a `date`. Also, `CASE` is an **expression**, it returns a scalar value. `Then dt=getdate() -1` doesn't make any sense; `dt=getdate() -1` isn't scalar value.

Comment: Ok i can use if statement right??

Comment: `IF` is a logical flow operator, you can't use it in a something like a `WHERE`, or `SELECT`.

Comment: Ok then what is the solution for it.....???? ☹️☹️

Comment: @Userabc No one can read your mind and give you suggestions about how to accomplish an undefined goal. Posting a non-working script **fragment** is not particularly useful in understanding your issue. And you throw a reference to a specific timezone but no one knows how that relates directly to your logic. You need to provide more information and more context.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you want to retrieve different rows depending on the time when the query is executed.

Using a `case` expression can work, but then you have to move the comparison with the `case` expression result *outside* the case expression.

So instead of:
`... where case when <condition> then (Column = Value1) else (Column = Value2) end`
do this:
`... where Column = (case when <condition> then Value1 else Value2 end)`
where the parentheses are added here for clarity.

**Sample data**

```
create table MyTable
(
  dt date,
  data nvarchar(20)
);

insert into MyTable (dt, data) values
('2021-03-08', 'yesterday''s data'),
('2021-03-09', 'today''s data');
```

**Solution**

Applying the construction from the start of my answer. Unit testing both options of the `case` expression will require a separate variable (or you could just wait hours and hours...).

*Requesting data on today's date in period [07:30, 11:59]*

```
declare @referenceDate smalldatetime = '2021-03-09 10:20';
--> using date variable instead of 'getdate()' for demo purposes !

select mt.dt,
       mt.data
from MyTable mt
where mt.dt = case
                when @referenceDate between '2021-03-09 07:30:00' and '2021-03-09 11:59:00'
                then dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, @referenceDate))
                else convert(date, @referenceDate)
              end;
--> returns data from yesterday
```

*Requesting data on today's date outside period [07:30, 11:59]*

```
declare @referenceDate smalldatetime = '2021-03-09 17:40';
--> using date variable instead of 'getdate()' for demo purposes !

select mt.dt,
       mt.data
from MyTable mt
where mt.dt = case
                when @referenceDate between '2021-03-09 07:30:00' and '2021-03-09 11:59:00'
                then dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, @referenceDate))
                else convert(date, @referenceDate)
              end;
--> returns data from today
```

*Requesting data on **any** date depending on period [07:30, 12:00]*

```
select mt.dt,
       mt.data
from MyTable mt
where mt.dt = case
                when convert(time, getdate()) >= '07:30:00'
                 and convert(time, getdate()) <  '12:00:00'
                then dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate()))
                else convert(date, getdate())
              end;
--> returns data from today OR yesterday depeding on time of execution (in/outside [07:30, 12:00])
```

Your question also mentions the [EST timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone). If you want the current execution time to be interpreted as EST, then have a look a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712616/convert-getdate-to-est/40495641) and [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql). Whether you should store data in EST instead of UTC in the first place is a whole other question... You will end up with something like this.

```
-- converting the query reference time to EST
declare @referenceDate smalldatetime = (select getdate() at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time');

select mt.dt,
       mt.data
from MyTable mt
where mt.dt = case
                when convert(time, @referenceDate) >= '07:30:00'
                 and convert(time, @referenceDate) <  '12:00:00'
                then dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, @referenceDate))
                else convert(date, @referenceDate)
              end;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4a36e04a4846f622b21714e70a6e4938) to see everything in action.